# Get song title from MPMediaItemCollection

Tags: swift, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm trying to rewrite my old player from Objective-C to Swift (by memory) and got in trouble. I've got array of songs like this

```
let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
query.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Title
songsArray = query.collections
```

Next in my table view I'm trying to get the name of each media item to put in the `cell.textLabel`. Like this:

```
var mediaItem = songsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
var title = mediaItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle)
```

But I'm not getting MPMediaItems, I'm getting the collection of items. So how can I take MPMediaItem from array of MPMediaItemCollections and get the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the collection grouping of the media items and get information about the group of tracks within them, you can access a MPMediaItem representative of the contents of a collection through MPMediaItemCollection's `representativeItem` property.

```
let collection = songsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! MPMediaItemCollection
let representativeItem = collection.representativeItem
let title = representativeItem.title
```

Side note, if you'd rather deal with an array of MPMediaItems, you may want to consider using MPMediaQuery's `items` property rather than its `collections` property.

Comment: I need the way to get my songs sorted) So i used collection) If u know another way to do it - please tell me